# Failed to get state by useLocation while it has Object data in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

## **First.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";



const First = () => {
    
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    return ( 
        <div className="First">
            <h1>This is First Input Page</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <dd>data 1</dd>
                <input
                    type="text" 
                    value={name} 
                    onChange={(e) => 
                        setName(e.target.value)
                    }
                    required
                ></input>
                <dd>data 2</dd>
                <input
                    type="text" 
                    value={phone} 
                    onChange={(e) => 
                        setPhone(e.target.value)
                    }
                    required
                ></input><br/>
                <Link to={'/second'} state={{ state: { name : name , phone : phone } }}><button>submit</button></Link>
            </form>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default First;
```

I try to send Object data using Link/state to another component.

## **Second.js**

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';



const Second = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    
    console.log(location.state);
    console.log(location.state.name);


    return ( 
        <div className="Second">
            <h1>This is Second Input Page</h1>
            <form>
                <dd>data 3</dd>
                <input></input>
                <dd>data 4</dd>
                <input></input><br/>
                <button>submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Second;
```

However, while I can access to (location.state), I can not access to (location.state.name). Why is that?

## **Output**

**state**: {name: 'Myname', phone: 'myphone'}

[[Prototype]]: Object

--------------------

undefined

The output shows that the code line "console.log(location.state);" works, but to the "console.log(location.state.name);", it shows undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you passed an object with `state` as the root property, i.e.

```
state={{ state: { name: name, phone: phone } }}
```

so to access it in the receiving route it is `location.state.state.name`.

You really don't need to nest the data you want to pass under a `state` property when using the `Link` component, it's not quite the same as when using the `navigate` function.

```
<Link to="/second" state={{ name, phone }}>
  <button>submit</button>
</Link>
```

It may also be considered semantically incorrect HTML to nest a button element within an anchor tag (*via `Link`*) element. Use the `useNavigate` hook and issue an imperative navigation action from the form's submit handler. In this case the `navigate` function's second argument, the options object`, *does* expect the state to be passed under the` state` property.

Example:

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const First = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("/second", { state: { name, phone } });
  };

  return ( 
    <div className="First">
      <h1>This is First Input Page</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <dd>data 1</dd>
        <input
          type="text" 
          value={name} 
          onChange={(e) => 
            setName(e.target.value)
          }
          required
        />
        <dd>data 2</dd>
        <input
          type="text" 
          value={phone} 
          onChange={(e) => 
            setPhone(e.target.value)
          }
          required
        />
        <br/>
        <button>submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
 
export default First;
```